# Are SQLAlchemy Core and ORM compatible?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I like using SQLAlchemy ORM to model my data in Python, but I need to use Core for some bulk inserts. Is it bad practice to just mix them? Are there unforeseen consequences to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't have any problems.  There are obviously differences, and the ORM has more "magic" working behind the scenes.  Doing a core operation will not, for example, update all the orm instances in memory.  ORM events won't fire for core actions.  Etc.  But ultimately, they are the same system.