# SQLAlchemy strategy: ORM + Core for classes with large amounts of data

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Apparently [use of ORM and Core in tandem is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31541840/are-sqlalchemy-core-and-orm-compatible/31569720#31569720), but I haven't been able to find any solid explanation of a strategy for this.

Here's the use case class:

```
class DataHolder(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'data_holder'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    dataset_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('data_set.id'))
    name = Column(String)

    _dataset_table = Table('data_set', Base.metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    )

    _datarows_table = Table('data_rows', Base.metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column('dataset_id', None, ForeignKey('data_set.id')),
        Column('row', Integer),
        Column('col_0', Integer),
        Column('col_1', Integer),
        Column('col_2', Integer),
    )

    def __init__(self, name=None, data=None):
        self.name = name
        self.data = data

    def _pack_info(self):
        # Return __class__ and other info needed for packing.

    def _unpack_info(self):
        # Return info needed for unpacking.
```

`name` should be persisted via [the ORM](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/). `data`, which would be a large NumPy array (or similar type), should be persisted via [the Core](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/index.html).

There is a go-between table `'data_set'` that exists for the purpose of a [many-to-one](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-one) relationship between `DataHolder` and the data. This allows data sets to exist independently within some library. (The sole purpose of this table is to generate IDs for new data sets.)

Actual persistence would be accomplished through a class that implements some listeners, such as the following.

```
class PersistenceManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.init_db()
        self.init_listeners()

    def init_db(self):
        engine = create_engine('sqlite:///path/to/database.db')
        self.sa_engine = engine
        self.sa_sessionmaker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    def init_listeners(self):
        @event.listens_for(Session, 'transient_to_pending')
        def pack_data(session, instance):
            try:
                pack_info = instance._pack_info()
                # Use Core to execute INSERT for bulky data.
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        @event.listens_for(Session, 'loaded_as_persistent')
        def unpack_data(session, instance):
            try:
                unpack_info = instance._unpack_info()
                # Use Core to execute SELECT for bulky data.
            except AttributeError:
                pass

    def persist(self, obj):
        session.add(obj)

    def load(self, class_, spec):
        obj = session.query(class_).filter_by(**spec).all()[-1]
        return obj

    def session_scope(self):
        session = self.sa_sessionmaker()
        try:
            yield session
            session.commit()
        except:
            session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            session.close()
```

The idea is that whenever a `DataHolder` is persisted, its data is also persisted at the same (or nearly the same) time.

Listening for `'transient_to_pending'` (for "packing") and `'loaded_as_persistent'` (for "unpacking") events will work for simple saving and loading. However, it seems care should be taken to also listen for the [`'pending_to_transient'`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_events.html#pending-to-transient) event. In the case of a [rollback](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html#rolling-back), the data added via Core will not be pulled back out of the database in the same way the ORM-related data will.

Is there another, better way to manipulate this behavior besides listening for `'pending_to_transient'`? This could cause problems in the case where two different `DataHolder`s reference the same data set: one `DataHolder` could rollback, removing the data set from the database so that the other `DataHolder` can no longer use it.